# Tomcat sessions expiring unexpectedly

Tags: java, session, tomcat

We are running tomcat application server that handle over 100 concurrent sessions.
In the last 2 months the most active users noticed that sometimes they are getting kicked off from the system.

As I understood from the log tomcat sessions are getting expired without any reason.

I see no problems from the web application side.
Is there any problem from the tomcat side?

Tomcat 6.0.18.

Comment: What did you find to be the cause?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there has been no code change triggering this, I would look at memory usage.  This *might* be the effect of Tomcat running out of memory and invalidating sessions to recover.

If at all possible monitor garbage collections, and/or put surveillance on with <strike>jconsole</strike> Java Flight Recorder or jvisualvm.

Answer (score 9):

A possible cause is that you put in the session an object that does NOT implement the Serializable interface. Tomcat occasionally writes some of the sessions on the disk. If a session contains non-serializable objects it will simply be removed from the container (because of the NotSerializableException). If this is happening you should see the Exception in the tomcat log file.

Comment: In what cases tomcat writes sessions on disk? in cluster based environment or when it is running out of memory?

Answer (score 5):

I would increase the monitoring of the server in general and the sessions specifically.

A good monitoring application is [lambda probe](http://www.google.com/search?q=lambda+probe&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a) - it allows you to view the current sessions and their data. I would also add a [HttpSessionListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to log session creation and destruction.

**Edit**

Is is possible that you add some non serializble objects to the session and Tomcat fails to passivate them to the disk?

**Edit 2**

Lambda probe seems to be dead, and there a much better fork of the project over at http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/

Answer (score 3):

there is a timeout, that you can configure in your web.xml:

```
<web-app>
  ...
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout> 
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

use -1 for no timeout

Comment: The problem is not there. Current timeout is set to one hour. But the users are getting kicked while actively using the application

Answer (score 2):

Increase your logging of sessions, which may shed some light onto your problem.

The Tomcat config page's [Logging in Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html) includes an example of increasing logging of sessions.

Answer (score 2):

We just ran into this with tomcat 6_0_18 and ibm 1.5 jvm

turns out it was an ibm jvm issue with atomic operations.

There is a fix in tomcats greater than 6_0_19 to handle it.

It also doesn't occur in sun 1.5 jvm

here are some more details

[tomcat bugzilla case](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46085)

Answer (score 2):

I have seen similar problems when the following prerequisites exist:

- multiple instances of the tomcat app are installed across multiple JVMs
- load balancing (between the web server and the Tomcat JVMs) is not configured correctly.
- Tomcat's session replication feature is **not** enabled

Due to the incorrect load balancing config, the web server may randomly decide to break session affinity and send an incoming request to a Tomcat JVM that has never seen the session before.  The Tomcat JVM will issue a new session and the user will lose all of their previouS session data and effectively start over.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how load balancing is not configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can search Tomcat's bug database, but it would be better to have another look at your web application first. The chances that there is something wrong with Tomcat are very low.

Try to investigate what causes session invalidation. Are you using filters? Do you have cross-context requests? Try adding logging information for every request to find out, when exactly the session is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar symptom (but more consistent). Users would sign in ok, go to the dashboard ok, then loose the session.
I realized I had done a Java 16 to 18 upgrade and had not recompiled everything. Cleaned (`mvn clean`) and recompiled the code for ALL my `.jars/.war`.

Problem solved, for me.
I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

Eventhough I do not know the cause of the problem, one possible fix (which I had done at my previous project) would be to run the application on a tomcat cluster and have session failover. Sessions can be by default sticky and when one node goes down, the healthy nodes pick up the sessions and all this is transparent to the end user.

Comment: It seems like clustering is more likely to cause problems with sessions than to fix them.