# Why I'm getting Session expired from Vaadin 6 application?

Tags: tomcat, vaadin, session-timeout

I have an application written with Vaadin 6 and I cannot switch to Vaadin 7.

I'm experiencing a problem with sessions.

In my web.xml configuration file I set session-timeout property to 120, but sometimes I get "Session expired" message from the application before 120 minutes, it seems that the session still lasts about 30 minutes.

My application is deployed on 2 balanced servers and I cannot access to the balancer server, but it uses Apache (can Apache destroy sessions before the application timeout?).

Any suggestion on how can I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>MyApplication</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>My Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>
            Vaadin application class to start</description>
            <param-name>application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <description>
            Application widgetset</description>
            <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.widgetset.MyApplicationWidgetset</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>My Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Could you show the contents of your `web.xml`?

Comment: @cNduo added my web.xml

Comment: Did you restart the app after setting this value?

Comment: Also, check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959174/tomcat-sessions-expiring-unexpectedly

Comment: @cNduo yes, i restarted it, redeployed too.

Comment: I would suggest adding `HttpSessionListener` to the app. This way you'll be able to monitor creations and destroyings of your sessions. If session lifetimes after last request vary, the issue may in the lack of available memory. Steps needed to add such listener: http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/

Comment: I don't know if in Vaadin 6 exist but you can add annotation  @PreserveOnRefresh

Comment: can you check stickiness of the session on balancer? if you have session on serverA, and, on next request, it lands on serverB, you may get a sessionExpired!